# My div is going up with site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My last div(actually last i want to have more divs) is going up with page (try to change height). And i have no idea why because my second is absolutely good.
Link here: https://vitas.sk/1/

HTML

```css
   .indexthird  {
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            background-image: url("http://vitas.sk/1/images/indexthird.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            min-height: 300px;
            
        }
        .indexthirdbbg{
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 7%;
        }
        
        .itquotes{
            
            font-size: 1.5vw;
        }
        .itautor {
            font-size: 1vw;
            margin-top: 1%;
            text-align: center
        }
```

```html
 <div class="indexthird"><div class="indexthirdbbg">
        <i class="itquotes">"„Kým budu ľudia masakrovať zvieratá, budú zabíjať aj jeden druhého.<br> Ten kto seje vraždu a bolesť, nemôže vypestovať radosť a lásku.“"</i>
      <p class="itautor">Pythagoras</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is why i posted link but give me moment i will post code.

Comment: Your code needs to be *in the question*.  When the code on your site changes, your question will lose any long-term value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```css
   .indexthird  {
            width: 100%;
            
            background-image: url("http://vitas.sk/1/images/indexthird.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            
        }
        .indexthirdbbg{
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            min-height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 7%;
        }
        
        .itquotes{
            
            font-size: 1.5vw;
        }
        .itautor {
            font-size: 1vw;
            margin-top: 1%;
            text-align: center
        }
```

```html
 <div class="indexthird"><div class="indexthirdbbg">
        <i class="itquotes">"„Kým budu ľudia masakrovať zvieratá, budú zabíjať aj jeden druhého.<br> Ten kto seje vraždu a bolesť, nemôže vypestovať radosť a lásku.“"</i>
      <p class="itautor">Pythagoras</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your second DIV (.indexsecond) has 80% height, which (obviously) changes with resize of the browser's widow. If I change the height to px (+ overflow:hidden), the behavior disappears.

Also, .indexthird has height in % and .indexthirdbbg has padding-top in %, which may add something to the behavior while resizing browser's window.

You can define window.onresize event and adjust divs programatically, with some sort of internal logic.

Comment: I dont understand. My first and second div works great. I have min height on all three. I want to have height in % on all because it makes them little bit responsive and when i use px i need more pagebreaks. Actually i cant define window.onresize i have some basic knowledge of html and css. I am planning to start with javascript on end of jannuary. Is there any way how i can set height in % or i need to change it to px?

Comment: @JurajJakubov simply remove the `height:80%` from second div and everything will be ok

Comment: Okay iam going to do it :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Bootstrap, add a “clearfix” div  before the last one

Comment: I have three divs (main parts of index page) i added class clearfix (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/) to my second div but it done nothing.